# Symfony EventListener

Tags: symfony, events, event-listener, symfony-3.3

I created some new events like `app.client_enter` or `app.client_leave`. Now I want to register a listener to listen on this events. If I add a listener in the same command, it's working.

*ClientListener.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;
use AppBundle\Event\ClientEnterEvent;

class ClientListener {

  public function onClientEnter(ClientEnterEvent $event) {
    echo "It could be working";
  }

}
```

*service.yml* (update)

```
services:
  app.client_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Service\ClientListener
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: app.client_enter, method: onClientEnter }
```

*ClientCommand.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use AppBundle\Event\ClientEnterEvent;

class ClientCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {
  protected function configure() { ... }
  protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    $dispatcher->dispatch('app.client_enter', new ClientEnterEvent("Maxi"));
}
```

Comment: Your tag is wrong.  Look closely at the example: https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#registering-the-listener

Comment: name: kernel.event_listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to all. I found the solution, in ContainerAwareCommand you have to use the service of event_dispatcher.

*ClientCommand.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use AppBundle\Event\ClientEnterEvent;

class ClientCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {
  protected function configure() { ... }
  protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $dispatcher = $this->getContainer->get('event_dispatcher');
    $dispatcher->dispatch('app.client_enter', new ClientEnterEvent("Maxi"));
}
```

After I used this service, my event trigger the listener.

Comment: yes event_dispatcher is the general container for events who manages the notifications, or as the docs say "The dispatcher is the central object". So when instanciating a new EventDispatcher there will be no listeners connected to it.

Answer (score 3):

It's `name: kernel.event_listener` for the tag

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip hoẃ to make this even better.

Since great Dependency Injection changes in **Symfony 3.3+** you can delegate many error prone code to Symfony.

#### Simplify Service Registration

```
# app/config/services.yml

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    AppBundle\:
        resouce: '../../src/AppBundle'
```

It doesn't work for listeners, because of extra tags, but it does for subscribers -  I recommend to use them to prevent any extra redundant config proramming.

#### Get Arguments The Clean Way - Via Constructor

Using that, you can use constructor injection in your commands out of the box.

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface

class ClientCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    private $eventDispatcher;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(...);
    }  
}
```

To read more about DI changes, see [this post with before/after examples](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/).